# How to set validation rules in file upload in code igniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to give validation for a file upload field in code giniter. I tried the below code, but this is not working. Any other way ?

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('photo', 'Passport Photo', 'required');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

except of client side verification with javascript, you can try the following in your controller:

```
if (empty($_FILES['photo']['name']))
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('photo', 'Passport photo', 'required');
}
```